# Get Log4j2 log file location

Tags: java, log4j2

How can I get the location of a log4j log file?
Log4j ver 2.3 Config:

```
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="ROLLLOGAPPENDER" fileName="./log/${infoFile}.log" filePattern="./log/${infoFile}-%i.log" append="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
        <ThresholdFilter level="${stdLevel}" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${sizeOfFile}" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="${filesCount}"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <Async name="ASYNC-LOG">
        <AppenderRef ref="ROLLLOGAPPENDER"/>
    </Async>
</Appenders>
```

But it doesn't work:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
...

LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
RollingFileAppender techical = (RollingFileAppender) config.getAppender(FILE_APPENDER_NAME);
```

java.lang.ClassCastException:

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender cannot be cast to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender
```

Comment: What is `FILE_APPENDER_NAME`?

Comment: OMG, i tried to get "ASYNC-LOG", thx!

Comment: Just curious why do you need to get the location of the log file from log4j rather than having log4j obtain the location through some other mechanism like JVM properties or environment variables?

Comment: if you start you application with -Dlog4j2.debug property it will show you the log config file:`DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration complete for context[name=*****] at URI /Users/*******/log4j_2/out/test/resources/log4j2-test.properties`

Comment: @D.B. I need a file with logs, and the place where it is saved.
I make a zip archive with a log, screenshot and send it to the mail for feedback

Comment: @A.Grin then my original question still stands. Why not configure log4j so that it will use JVM properties and/or environment variables to build the path to the log file(s)? Whatever code that builds the archive can then use the same variables to build the path to the log file. By externalizing the log path like this you will remove your dependency on the log4j implementation and reduce long term maintenance.